# error Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'href')

Tags: python-3.x, plotly, plotly-dash, dashboard

Can anyone tell me why I get this message when running my Dash project?

**Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'href')
16:21:53
Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'href')
(This error originated from the built-in JavaScript code that runs Dash apps. Click to see the full stack trace or open your browser's console.)**

When running the project it loads and displays this message, I notice that on line 41 where there is dbc.Row(dbc.Col([theme_switch])), is the cause of the problem.

```
import dash
from dash import html, dcc, Input, Output, State
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import pandas as pd

# import from folders/theme changer
from app import *
from dash_bootstrap_templates import ThemeSwitchAIO

# import theme changer
from dash_bootstrap_templates import ThemeSwitchAIO

# ================================================================== #
from flask import Flask

server = Flask(__name__)
app = dash.Dash(__name__,  server=server, suppress_callback_exceptions=True)

# ============================Styles================================ #
tab_card = {'height': '100%'}

template_theme1 = 'zephyr'
template_theme2 = 'solar'
url_theme1 = dbc.themes.ZEPHYR
url_theme2 = dbc.themes.SOLAR

theme_switch = ThemeSwitchAIO(aio_id="theme", themes=[url_theme1, url_theme2])

app.layout = dbc.Container([
dcc.Store(id='dataset'),

# Layout
# Row 1
dbc.Row([
    dbc.Col([
        dbc.Card([
            dbc.CardBody([
                dbc.Row(dbc.Col([theme_switch])),
                dbc.Row([
                    dbc.Button("Visite o Site", href="https://ajuda.alterdata.com.br/suporteexpress", target="_blank")
                ], style={'margin-top': '10px'})
            ])
        ], style=tab_card)
    ], sm=4, lg=2),
    dbc.Col([
        dbc.Card([
            dbc.CardBody([
                dcc.Graph(id='graph0', className='dbc', config={"displayModeBar": False, "showTips": False})
            ])
        ], style=tab_card)
    ], sm=12, lg=10)
], className='g-2 my-auto', style={'margin-top': '7px'}),

], fluid=True, style={'height': '100vh'})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

[image]

Even without the brackets the error remains.

Comment: Please post the full error message.

Comment: Please try to remove the brackets from  dbc.Row(dbc.Col([theme_switch]))

Comment: I edited the question and reported the error image.
Even without the brackets the problem occurs.

Answer (score 1):

As you're using dash-bootstrap-components for the layout, you have to set the external stylesheets parameter for the app object, like this:

```
app = dash.Dash(__name__,  server=server, suppress_callback_exceptions=True, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])
```

**Reason Behind the error**:

When the app's layout first loads up, it's unable to find the stylesheet for bootstrap components so it falls back to simple HTML components and the html.Button doesn't have a 'href' property hence you get an internal javascript error.
But later on, as you're also using dash-bootstrap-templates library, when you create the ThemeSwitchAIO object, the app uses the underlying bootstrap stylesheet from this library due to which you'd have also noticed that the styles don't get affected.

Comment: Perfect, an explanation that I didn't see in the course I bought.
Thanks to everyone who commented on this post.